# I am a beginner and i was building a card game as little project . i am having a problem with while loop ,plz guide me

Tags: python

in below code i have created function named cards_game in which it will give you random card which will be added to cards list . if we input "hit" then it will give you random no. which simultaneously added to the cards list then [ if you input "stay" then it will stop while loop and will check the sum and if the sum >= 21 then it will stop while loop and run next code ] <--- but this is problem , it repeats the same line in last 'else' condition. If you input hit it will ask for it again rather than proceeding..

sorry if i have elaborated my question badly ...but this my 1st time on this platform
please pardon me and guide me , i would be very grateful for you .

```
def cards_game():
    cards = []
    seed(1)
    sequence= [i for i in range(10)]
    print ("Now you will get to select 1 random card \n but to get that there is 1 code called \"hit\" \nAnd to not to pick card there will be code called \"stay\" ")
    x = True
    command = input("what would you like to do?\n>>> ")
    while x :
        if command == 'hit':
            cards.append(sample(sequence,1))

        elif command == 'stay':
            "ok"
            sum = 0
            for i in cards:
                sum = sum + i
            if sum >= 21:
                x = False
            else:
                print ("too bad!\n I think you are anout to spend your \nWhole life playing with me \nHAHHHAHHAHAHAAAAAAAAAAHAHAHAAHHAAAA")
                
        else:
            print("Bad command")
        
    
    
cards_game()
```

Comment: you are taking only one input, `command = input("what would you like to do?\n>>> ")`, if given `'hit'`, loop runs infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Taking input one time is one of the issue, include it in your while loop,

```
....
while x :
    command = input("what would you like to do?\n>>> ")
    if command == 'hit':
....
```

You don't have to make sequence list, simply use randint() funciton

```
import random
....
if command == 'hit':
    cards.append(random.randint(1,10))
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only ask the player once what move to do. The command input should be in the loop.

```
from random import *
def cards_game():
    cards = []
    seed(1)
    sequence= [i for i in range(10)]
    print ("Now you will get to select 1 random card \n but to get that there is 1 code called \"hit\" \nAnd to not to pick card there will be code called \"stay\" ")
    x = True
    while x :
        command = input("what would you like to do?\n>>> ")
        if command == 'hit':
            cards.append(sample(sequence,1))

        elif command == 'stay':
            "ok"
            som = 0
            for i in cards:
                som = som + i
            if som >= 21:
                x = False
            else:
                print ("too bad!\n I think you are anout to spend your \nWhole life playing with me \nHAHHHAHHAHAHAAAAAAAAAAHAHAHAAHHAAAA")
                
        else:
            print("Bad command")
cards_game()
```

Your code still doesn't compile, because the elements in cards are a list, since sample returns a list. I would advise you to replace it by choice, in random module too.

`cards.append(choice(sequence))`